# How to display download file popup (not a new window)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, download

I try to display "save as" popup on IE using javascript (jquery is ok too).
The expected result is:
[image]

I use this code:

```
window.open("some url on my server", "_self");
```

and I get:
[image]

How can I make it look like in the first picture? as a popup at the bottom of the page, and not modal like I get..

Comment: This can't be done with JavaScript. You have to set the HTTP headers, and this can only be done on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this with JavaScript or jQuery. You need to set the HTTP headers of the request as follows:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=excel1.xlsx');
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
```

The above is a PHP example. Telling the browser to handle the request as an octet stream will prompt the user with the `Save As...` dialogue.